# How to restore app's state after preferred language change?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI (if it matters in this case) and I am interested in my app working on iOS 13 and up.

My app has 2 languages. I have added Settings.bundle file and now I can see PREFERRED LANGUAGE settings for my app. So far so good.

The problem is that when I change the language, app relaunches and resets. I would like to preserve its state.

During one of Apple's WWDC presentation it was said to take this approach (following is text from Apple's slides):

> **ViewController State Restoration**
>
> Changing languages via Settings will relaunch your application Enable
> state restoration in your AppDelegate with:
>
> application(_:shouldSaveApplicationState:)
>
> application(_:shouldRestoreApplicationState:)
>
> Set restorationIdentifier on controllers to make language switching
> seamless

And this:

> **Scene State Restoration**
>
> Enable state restoration in your SceneDelegate
> with:
>
> stateRestorationActivity(for scene:)
>
> Return an NSUserActivity object that encodes your scene state

But those informations are very brief and I don't know how to implement the code from those examples. I have also found this article in Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/restoring_your_app_s_state
But it is way more complicated than those slides from WWDC presentation. In this article they write that there are 2 different approaches: for iOS 13 and up and for 12 and earlier. As I mentioned already, I am only interested in iOS 13 and up. What is the simplest way to make it work?

I did try to find a solution here. And tried to find a tutorial on Google and Youtube. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me you are looking for a tutorial on SwiftUI and state restoration. Try this one here:

**UIScene State Restoration with NSUserActivity and SwiftUI on iOS 13 (iPadOS)**

*Multi-window support introduces fundamental changes to the life cycle of iOS 13 and iPadOS apps. It’s closely connected with the concept of a scene, which represents a single instance of your app’s user interface. Every scene has its own life cycle and there can be more than one scene running at the same time.
I am explaining what are scenes and how they are put together in iOS 13 (iPadOS) App Life Cycle with UIScene.*

*Since the system manages your app scenes, it may connect and disconnect scenes to reclaim their resources. In this case the user interface is gone and will be replaced with a snapshot. The next time the user opens that scene, they will face an initial window with all unfinished work lost.*

*The solution is per-scene state restoration, which becomes a vital feature for rich user experience beginning from iOS 13 (iPadOS). In this article let’s find out how to implement scene-based state restoration with NSUserActivity and SwiftUI.*

https://www.vadimbulavin.com/ios13-ipados-uiscene-state-restoration-with-nsuseractivity-and-swiftui/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it tomorrow or on Friday and get back to you. Today I am out of office

Comment: Ok FYI I downloaded the sample project and it worked (it’s at the end of the page)